# Grouping lists of numbers together in Python

Tags: python, grouping

I have the following which is a list of a list in Python, and is a partial list of values that I have:

```
[1,33]
[2,10,42]
[5,1,33,44]
[10,42,98]
[44,12,100,124]
```

Is there a way of grouping them so they collect the values that are common in each list?

For example, if I look at the first list [1,33], I can see that the value exists in the third list: [5,1,33,44]

So, those are grouped together as

[5,1,33,44]

If I carry on looking, I can see that 44 is in the final list, and so that will be grouped along with this list.

[44,12,100,124] is added onto [5,1,33,44]

to give:
[1,5,12,33,44,100,124]

The second list [2,10,42]  has common values with [10,42,98] and are therefore joined together to give:
[2,10,42,98]

So the final lists are:

```
[1,5,12,33,44,100,124]

[2,10,42,98]
```

I am guessing there is a specific name for this type of grouping.  Is there a library available that can deal with it automatically?  Or would I have to write a manual way of searching?

I hope the edit makes it clearer as to what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the grouping?  Can you explain how you're getting from a to b?

Comment: this is arbitrary grouping. The logic is unclear. Voting to close

Comment: as far as I can tell from what you have posted, the library module that can help you there is `random`.

Comment: Not voting to close yet, but sure the OP needs to clarify what is the criteria for this grouping.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Looks like every other list should be concated - elements in lists 1, 3, and 5 are in the first, 2 and 4 are in the second.

Comment: @BradSolomon I can't vote to reopen, but the criteria seems clear to me - distinct elements in the odd and even indexed lists.

Comment: @ryachza That is a _possibility_, but unless OP clarifies it is hardly definitive.

Comment: Yep - even if these are the criteria, unless they are clarified in the text, the question is useless for anyone else anyway.

Comment: The whole idea is to group lists that have the same values together.

Comment: @csstudent, could one of the lists share only some item, not all? Let's say the 1st list is `[1, 32]` and the 3rd is `[5,1,33,44]` ?

Comment: Yes, that situation would mean that those two would join together to form one list, therefore: [5,1,32,33,44].  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that does not require anything from the standard library or 3rd party packages.  *Note that this will modify `a`*.  To avoid that, just make a copy of `a` and work with that.  The result is a list of lists containing your resulting sorted lists.

```
a = [
     [1,33],
     [2,10,42],
     [5,1,33,44],
     [10,42,98],
     [44,12,100,124]
    ]

res = []
while a:
    el = a.pop(0)
    res.append(el)
    for sublist in a:
        if set(el).intersection(set(sublist)):
            res[-1].extend(sublist)
            a.remove(sublist)
res = [sorted(set(i)) for i in res]
print(res)
# [[1, 5, 12, 33, 44, 100, 124], [2, 10, 42, 98]]
```

How this works:

- Form an empty result list `res`.  Groupings from `a` will be "transferred" here.
- `.pop()` off the first element of `a`.  This modifies `a` in place and defines `el` as that element.
- Then loop through each sublist in `a`, comparing your popped `el` to those sublists and "building up" common sets.  This is where your problem is a tiny bit tricky in that you need to gradually increment your intersected set rather than finding the intersection of multiple sublists all at once.
- Repeat this process until `a` is empty.

Alternatively, if you just want to group together the even- and odd-numbered sublists (still a bit unclear from your question), you can use itertools:

```
from itertools import chain
grp1 = sorted(set(chain.from_iterable(a[::2])))
grp2 = sorted(set(chain.from_iterable(a[1::2])))
print(grp1)
print(grp2)
# [1, 5, 12, 33, 44, 100, 124]
# [2, 10, 42, 98]
```